# Compile error using ScalaTest?

Tags: scala, junit, scalatest

I get a weird error when using ScalaTest.
I have the following code:

```
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnit3Suite;
import Element.elem;

class ElementSuite extends JUnit3Suite {

  def testD() {
    val ele = elem('x', 2, 3);
    assert(ele.width === 2);
  }

}
```

I get a compile error saying " illegal inheritance; self-type ElementSuite does not conform to org.scalatest.junit.JUnit3Suite's selftype 
 org.scalatest.junit.JUnit3Suite"

any ideas??

Note I took this example straight from Martin Oderskey's book so it should work fine...

Comment: Don't know, but I don't think JUnit3Suite is widely used, and Scalatest has been through a few versions since Odersky wrote his book. I've always used Funsuite - try that instead?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say exactly what the problem is not knowing which version of Scala,
SBT, Scalatest, etc you're using, but this works using more recent releases.
Rather than trying to determine precisely where the disconnect is with the old
version, I think you'll have an easier time with the current version.

build.sbt:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Sonatype releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
  )
libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "2.2.6"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.6" % "test"
```

Test class:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

// Random implementation because I'm not sure what Martin's elem class is.
case class elem( someField: Char, width: Int, height: Int )

class ElemSuite extends FunSuite {
  test("D") {
    val ele = elem('x', 2, 3)
      assert(ele.width === 2)
  }
}
```

I think this is the closest match you'll get to the code in the book. However,I like using FlatSpec and FeatureSpec along with Matchers when writing my tests:

```
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}

class ElemSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers
{
  it should "retrieve the correct width"  in {
    val ele = elem('x', 2, 3)
    ele.width shouldBe 2
  }
}
```

However if you're new to Scala, you might be better of sticking to the style that
matches the book.

More info on ScalaTest styles: http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/selecting_a_style

Disclaimer: I'm actually using the latest 3.0.0 release candidate, but I
*think* these simple tests will still work for you using 2.2.6.